# Dapper Deadlock issue

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008-r2, data-access-layer, dapper

I am using two web projects and both using same Database of MS SQL server 2008 R2 and both projects interacting to database through Dapper ORM, I am getting some ( 7 to 8 / day ) deadlock exceptions. Is it dapper's issue or my fault? Can anybody suggest me solution? I can provide more info if you need.

Comment: Please be sure to include a language tag specific to your question so people monitoring the tags can find your question. I'll flag it .NET shortly to provide greater exposure, though please refine it to the specific language you're having trouble with. Additionally a code sample would likely help potential helpers.

Comment: Providing more info would greatly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely you.  Dapper translates everything into normal ADO.Net command objects.  It works off of the IDbConnection interface via extension methods.  I can't think of a way that it could cause a deadlock by itself.  Please provide a minimal, repeatable example of your issue in play.

I'm fairly sure that it's a concurrency issue in your code.

If this example can be run without Dapper (i.e. pure SQL), then we can rule Dapper out as a cause.